# Пока не авторизуется открывать одну и ту же страницу сайта

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, аутентификация

Есть приложение на asp.net mvc. При создании приложения выбрал тип аутентификации No Authentication. Хочу использовать аутентификацию форм. Мне нужно что бы приложение всегда стартовало с одной и той же страницы. Даже если я из visual studio открываю на редактирование другую view и запускаю проект, всё равно перенаправлялось на дефолтную страницу. Нашёл что нужно написать в web config что бы так работало приложение.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Authorization/Index" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

Написал это в web config.
У меня например есть 2 страницы регистрация и авторизация. Я выбираю на редактирование в visual studio view за которую отвечает другой метод этого же контроллера `/Authorization/Registration` запускаю приложение и у меня запускается страница регистрации. То есть не срабатывает переадрессация на страницу авторизации. Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так? Как нужно сделать так что бы срабатывала переадрессация?

Comment: Сумбурно как-то. Если вы хотите, чтобы приложение при открытии какой-то страницы открывало всегда одну жёстко заданную, то как вы будете вообще различать, нужно ли вам показывать эту страницу или показать заданную? Вы же не хотите накатать сайт на 100500+ страниц, но чтобы при выкатке в продакшн показывалась только одна жестко заданная? Ибо что бы вы ни открыли - у вас всегда будет показываться заданная. Смысла в таком приложении нет! Тогда что вы имели ввиду?

Comment: `Мне нужно что бы приложение всегда стартовало с одной и той же страницы.` приложение - это сервер. Сервер не стартует ни с какой станицы.

Comment: `другой метод этого же контроллера /Authorization/Registration запускаю приложение и у меня запускается страница регистрации. То есть не срабатывает переадрессация` а как пользователи будут у вас регистрироваться? Зачем вообще нужна страница регистрации тогда?

Comment: @tym32167 я имел в виду что при запуске приложения должна запускаться страница авторизации. А на регистрацию пользователи пройдут нажав кнопку зарегистрироваться и так далее, но запускаться приложение должно всегда с одной и той же

Comment: `При создании приложения выбрал тип аутентификации No Authentication. Хочу использовать аутентификацию форм` там разве нет опции при создании для вашей аутентификации? Почему выбрали No Authentication?

Comment: @AK может я не правильно выразился, мне нужно что бы приложение запускалось всегда с одной и той же страницы пока человек не авторизуется.

Comment: @tym32167 пример с метанита, аутентификация форм https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/12.5.php

Comment: Возможно, вам вполне достаточно того, чтобы всё приложение было доступно только авторизованным пользователям? Открываешь стартовую или любую другую - а там форма "введите логин/пароль или зарегистрируйтесь". Хотите так? Только чтобы понимать: поисковики не индексируют сайты с авторизацией.

Comment: Да, нужно что бы такой сайт был. Если пользователь не авторизован, всегда перенаправлялось на страницу авторизации или регистрации

Comment: Мне кажется, вам надо смотреть в сторону сессии, только так вы на странице регистрации поймете, что юзер ее первой открыл, минуя страницу авторизации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> мне нужно что бы приложение запускалось всегда с одной и той же страницы пока человек не авторизуется

Воткните в каждый экшн первой строкой код вида:

```
if (user==null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Если такое поведение вас устраивает - можете написать [кастомный фильтр](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/8.2.php), в который вынести эту проверку, чтобы не писать каждый раз.

Comment: AK и прицепить этот фильтр как атрибут к каждому экшену в приложении?

Comment: @Андрей Ну или [глобально](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/8.6.php).

Comment: `при запуске приложения должна запускаться страница авторизации. А на регистрацию пользователи пройдут нажав кнопку зарегистрироваться` вы уверены, что это будет работать?

Comment: @tym32167 А почему нет? Разумеется, я не попробовал (я давно уже классический mvc не запускаю), но не вижу причин почему не должно сработать. Разумеется, нужно будет прописать исключения для редиректа для страниц авторизации, чтобы их можно было увидеть -- но мне кажется, что это очевидно. Других причин мне пока не приходит в голову.

Comment: ну, например, юзер заходит на страницу авторизации. Как в фильтре понять, что юзер на неё зашел со страницы аутентификации или зашел напрямую по ссылке? Тут вашего кода ведь будет не достаточно.

Comment: @tym32167 я подозреваю что можно просто на action который отвечает за страницу регистрации не вешать фильтр вот и всё и туда пустит.

Comment: @AK а что вы имели в виду под ` Разумеется, нужно будет прописать исключения для редиректа для страниц авторизации, чтобы их можно было увидеть` можно по подробнее?

Comment: @Андрей но тогда же пустит на регистрацию, минуя страницу авторизации?

Comment: @tym32167, да вы правы, а в вопросе я просил именно к одной странице, согласен. Можно тогда извернуться и определять откуда мы идём по ссылке сразу или из формы авторизации, можно что то передать какой нибудь параметр, хеш или что то ещё, но способов думаю не мало. Но я понял ваше замечание, спасибо.

Comment: @Андрей поэтому я вам и написал про сессию в комментах, по ней вы сможете понять, только что юзер зашел или уже был на сайте.

Comment: @tym32167 да спасибо за вариант. А подскажите пожалуйста определение авторизован ли пользователь в примере фильтра с метанита который синул AK там же тоже если не ошибаюсь в сессии храниться? Если закрыть все экземпляры браузера и зайти заново, то снова нужно будет авторизовываться и не куда не пустит пока не авторизуешься?

Comment: @tym32167 и ещё такой вопрос, если можно сделать то что мне нужно с помощью фильтров, для чего же тогда вообще код в web config который я нашёл `<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Authorization/Index" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>` что он делает тогда?

Comment: @Андрей я не веб разработчик, но, если мне память не изменяет, то ид сессии хранится в куках, потому, скорее всего, при рестарте браузера, сессия подхватится, если куки не успеют протухнуть

Comment: Фильтрами вы понимаете, надо редиректить юзера или нет,  аутентификация позволяет по логину и паролю найти юзера, авторизация позволяет понять какие у юзера роли. То есть это все разные вещи, которые выполняют разную работу

Comment: @tym32167, по поводу браузера понял. А по поводу последнего комментария я имел в виду что мою задачу можно реализовать с помощью фильтра и написанного в нём метода для редиректа. А для чего нужны строки веб конфига которые я привёл в вопросе? Что они тогда делают? Я немного не понял их предназначение.

Comment: @Андрей, без этого `<authentication mode="Forms"..` когда юзер укажет свой логин и пароль на форме аутентификации и попробует зайти на сайт, он этого не сможет сделать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88183/discussion-between--and-tym32167).

Comment: @AK а подскажите пожалуйста как тогда если повесить фильтр глобально на всё приложение, исключить нужные мне контроллеры или отдельные экшены контроллеров из этого фильтра?